# Delphi: trouble calling function returning interface

Tags: delphi, function, interface

I'm trying to call a function returning an interface from another unit; for instance consider the following:

```
program intf_sb1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  myunit in 'myunit.pas';
var
  MyBL: ISomeInterface;
begin
  MyBL := GetInterface;
end.
```

where the content of `myunit.pas` is as follows:

```
unit myunit;
interface
type
  ISomeInterface = interface
    ['{D25A26ED-7665-4091-9B0F-24DF37545E2A}']
  end;
implementation

function GetInterface : ISomeInterface;
begin
end;

end.
```

My problem is that I get the error "E2003 Undecleared identifier GetInterface" when I try to run this program. Why isn't this allowed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is suggest another name than 'GetInterface' because that is a predefined method in every TObject.

Comment: Conciliator, you've phrased your question as though the source of the problem has something to do with the fact the function returns an interface type. Before jumping to that conclusion, you should do some investigation of your own. If that was really the problem, then you should have been able to *change the return type* to make the function work. You obviously didn't try that. Don't give up so easily; it makes you look *lazy*.

Comment: Rob: That's true indeed. I apologize for the apparent laziness; I guess I'm just not used to Delphi yet, splitting code in the interface and implementation sections.
Uwe: Thanks, that's a very good point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Declare the GetInterface function in the interface section as well. If you don't it is "private" to the unit.

IE:

```
type
  ISomeInterface
  ...
  end;

  function GetInterface: ISomeInterface;

implementation

function GetInterface: ISomeInterface;
begin
...
end;
```